# iPhone 6s Plus can't Open Setting

Tags: ios, objective-c

Why below code can't open 'Setting' in iPhone 6s Plus with iOS9.2.1, but can in iPhone 6s.

```
 NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"prefs:root=WIFI"];    
 if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:url]) {      
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];   
  }
```

Comment: You can try call this in main queue if not.

Comment: Did you specify "prefs" as `LSApplicationQueriesSchemes` in your Info.plist?

Comment: thank you very much. I Add 'prefs' in info.plist at 'URL Types' -> 'URL Schemes'  box it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Detail should be this : go to

**Target -> Info -> URL Types**

add item like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:UIApplicationOpenSettingsURLString]];
```

Comment: thanks, it can work. but I want to jump to Setting -> WIFI page.